# Polymorphic Association not working with ActiveHash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveHash class that I'd like to use in a polymorphic association:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveHash::Associations::ActiveRecordExtensions

  belongs_to :placeable, polymorphic: true
end

class Country < ActiveHash::Base
  include ActiveHash::Associations

  has_many :people, as: :placeable

  self.data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'US' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Canada' }
  ]
end
```

When setting the polymorphic association, it persists to the database setting the polymorphic type to `ActiveHash::Base`. When accessing it later, I receive an `undefined method 'arel_table'` error.

```
person = Person.create
person.placeable = Country.last
person.save
person
=> #<Person id: 1, placeable_id: 2, placeable_type: "ActiveHash::Base">

person.placeable
NoMethodError: undefined method `arel_table' for ActiveHash::Base:Class
    from (irb):2
```

I've also tried setting the polymorphic type to `Country`, but I receive the same error for the Country class.

A non-polymorphic `belongs_to` seems to work fine.

Comment: Are you sure if that is even supported by that ActiveHash gem? Sound like it just isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Doc: https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash/issues/151

**

> ActiveHash does not support **arel** behaviour.

**

**Arel** is a SQL AST (Abstract Syntax Tree-like) manager for Ruby. It allows us to write complex SQL queries in a semantic, reusable fashion. Arel is "framework framework"; it's designed to optimize object and collection modeling over database compatibility. **Active Record is built on top of Arel**.

see Doc: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/honkster-active_hash/0.7.3

Even in this official doc, it doesn't explain anywhere  like this:

```
has_many :people, as: :placeable
```

Just explain

```
belongs_to :placeable, polymorphic: true
```